# good online resources for 2nd-order system dynamics

Tags: control-theory, online-resources

I'm looking for good online resources for 2nd order system dynamics. Any recommendations?

I'm looking for stuff that ideally includes discussion of Q, damping ratio, overshoot, bode plots, for systems with transfer functions  of

$$ H_1(s) = \frac{1}{\tau_2^2 s^2 + \tau_1 s + 1} $$

$$ H_2(s) = \frac{\tau_1 s + 1}{\tau_2^2 s^2 + \tau_1 s + 1} $$

and

$$ H_3(s) = \frac{s}{\tau_2^2 s^2 + \tau_1 s + 1} $$

---

**edit:** I've done change of variables to rewrite as

$$ H_1(\sigma) = \frac{1}{\sigma^2 + 2\zeta\sigma + 1} $$

$$ H_2(\sigma) = \frac{2\zeta\sigma + 1}{\sigma^2 + 2\zeta\sigma + 1} $$

and

$$ H_3(\sigma) / \omega_0 = \frac{\sigma}{\sigma^2 + 2\zeta\sigma + 1} $$

where $\sigma = \tau_2 s = s / \omega_0$, $\omega_0 = 1 / \tau_2$, and $\zeta = \tau_1 / 2\tau_2$ to normalize out the time scaling factor and end up with a transfer function of the single variable $\zeta$ (damping factor) which I think is the conventional treatment.

Comment: Community Wiki.

Comment: done. (.......)

Answer (score 1):

Searching in Google itself gives you a great deal of information. I got this link which explains has the content which you need.

- http://www.facstaff.bucknell.edu/mastascu/econtrolhtml/SysDyn/SysDyn2.html

Next, [redacted: inappropriate link to pirated content] is an excellent source for those who are in need of books online.

Comment: the problem is there are a lot of mediocre pages out there, and I'm looking for a good one; most of the sources of this type of information just have the transfer function with 1 in the numerator and something in the denominator. (having said that, the one you posted isn't too bad)